# How to write custom select/checkmark logic for material-table, to include selected rows inside of detail panel nested material-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

I have a [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/) component where I am rendering a nested materiel-table in the detail panel of each row. I would like to know if there is a way to include detail panel material-table rows in the functions offered by the package. I am mainly interested in the [selection](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/selection) feature for now, but will likely need the same support for other functions like filtering, search, etc...

Now I know that [Tree Data](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/tree-data) allows this since all rows are part of the same table. But I need to be able to do it with using the Detail Panel.

NB: For more clarity, [here is a code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/restaurant-menu-as-material-table-with-nested-material-table-detail-panel-osihz?file=/src/App.js) I found with the nested table functionality.

So how would one go about adding their custom select function to a material-table, such as to include selected rows inside nested material-tables ?

Comment: I don't fully understand what is the matter here: do you want to add a selection feature to the outer table? So that when you select a row in the outer table the rows in the inner table would be selected too?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to control the row checked state outside of the table, meaning without using the provided check box inputs, is demonstrated in a demo created after I asked the same question in the [material-table-core](https://github.com/material-table-core/core) repo. It's pretty straight forward and should help anyone trying to do the same : https://material-table-core.com/demos/selection/outside-of-table/